# How to use bootstrap styles on print page with Asp.net bundling

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstraps row/column grid on a print page, however when I go to the print preview all of the rows and columns are missing.  I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023453/how-to-add-media-attribute-to-asp-net-mvc4-style-bundle) solution and have the link tag showing in my html correctly:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Still, this shows on the screen:

[image]

And this shows on the print preview:

[image]

How do I get my bootstrap styles to show on the print preview and printed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12078), Bootstrap 3 considers the paper page to be less than 768px wide, so it displays the mobile version of the page. You should probably create a special print stylesheet for the printed view.

Alternately, you should be able to get around this by adding xs classes to your grid, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <h1>First Name</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <h1>Middle Initial</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <h1>Last Name</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!-- Next row -->
</div>
```

This isn't a great idea though, because a printed view is different from a small viewport, so it's better practice to create a separate print stylesheet.

Comment: I will be creating a separate print stylesheet, however, it would be nice to be able to use bootstrap's grid layout.  I'm curious if there are any alternatives to this.