# Print a hidden div using Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**HTML**

```
 <div id="printcontent">
    //some data: mostly images
        </div>
```

I want to print the above div using Media Queries.

Please note that the above div is set to: Display:none; in css;

Here is the Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Ryh3G/

The print dialog is not appearing. It should work in all browsers.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It works good.choose `'No wrap - in <head>'` in right sidebar @fiddle

```
function functionPrint()
{    
 window.print();   
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryh3G/1/)

Comment: what is no-wrap in head?

Comment: It just means that the script is added in the <head> section of the <html>

From JSFiddle Docs,

    no wrap(head): do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <head> section

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why the same code is printing white page in my asp.net applcation?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042248/make-asp-net-bundling-specify-media-screen-for-css-bundle